# Effective way to get array index and value names

Tags: php, arrays

I have a 0 indexed array that I can't do much about, but inside this array there are values that I need to echo. example array is:

```
$x =  array(0 => array('store'=> 107));
```

I would like to have 2 variables that both echo texts `store` and `107`

I could do this, using

```
$var1 = array_keys($x[0]); 
$var2 = array_values($x[0]); 

echo $var1[0]; // store 
echo $var2[0]; // 107
```

I would like to know if there is a more effective way of getting those values, or remving that first `0` index. as `array_filter($x)` or `unset($x)` obviously don't work as in other cases.

Comment: It's only the one element at `[0]` you will need to get at?

Comment: `$x = $x[0]` will give `$x = array('store'=> 107)` and you may keep it like that

Comment: You could use `current($x)` instead of `$x[0]`. I don't see the benefit, though.

Comment: thanks @Barmar I didn't know current could be used for this. Although there Nordenheim's answer is neat also. I suppose you don't think there is any different to from memory footprint side, even though it is too small to scale. I just got curious to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an alternative, you could also use combinations of `key()` and `reset()` if you're curious.

```
$x =  array(0 => array('store'=> 107));

$y = reset($x); // point to first element
$key = key($y); // get the current key, store
$val = reset($y); // get the value
echo $key; // store
echo $val; // 107
```

Answer (score 1):

this should work for you.

```
$x =  array(0 => array('store'=> 107));

foreach($x as $y){
    foreach ($y as $key => $value){
        echo $key;
        echo $value;
    }
}
```